# Regex - Textfield pattern with number range and optional single letter

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern for a textfield, valid entries would be any number not starting with 0 up to 9999 with an optional A-Z or a-z character at end

```
<input name="field1" id="field1" pattern="^(?!(0\d))\d{1,4}([A-Za-z]?)">
```

e.g. of valid entries would be:

```
1
12
123
1A
12B
123C
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please update your post with more details such as what you have tried and what doesn't work, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the following regex pattern:

```regex
^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}[A-Za-z]?$
```

Your updated HTML code:

```html
<input name="field1" id="field1" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]{0,3}[A-Za-z]?$">
```